# How to test if double value is not negative

Tags: c++, c++11, double

I failed to google this so I'm asking how to properly and conclusively test double value to be greater then or equal to 0.

I'm somehow aware of double problematic zero value (the ± 0.0 and so on) and I need to check wheter my double variable is greater then or equal to 0. Or else and maybe better if is it not negative.

The question is, can i test this like this:
`if(myDoubleValue >= 0.0)` (i think this one could be problematic)
or will be better something like this:
`if(!(myDoubleValue < 0.0))`

Sorry for probably dumb question.

Comment: Why do you _think_ the first option is problematic?

Comment: @yman well, just a feeling. I think that the two options won't give the exact same result, but i could be wrong, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value ±0 only indicates if the value approached 0 from negative or positive values (but this is not a guarantee for every case, of course). However, it still *is* 0.

Therefore, `x >= 0` will include both +0 and -0 zero. You can test that for yourself in a simple program. :)

In the [IEEE754 standard](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/servlet/opac?punumber=4610933), it explicitly says

> Comparisons shall ignore the sign of zero (so +0 = -0).

IEEE754 is used by most processors and implementations, so for all practical purposes `-0 >= 0` is true.

For any number x, `x >= 0` and `!(x < 0)` are the same. This is also true for +0 and -0.

---

As pointed out by aschepler in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511246/how-to-test-if-double-value-is-not-negative/40511313#comment68264729_40511313), the two tests `x >= 0` and `!(x < 0)` differ when x is NaN (not-a-number). NaN is always different from any real number, thus `!(x < 0)` will be true when x is NaN.
If NaN can occur in your calculations, you may want to handle that separately.

Comment: I edited the question, i forgot to say in text, that i need greater then or equal to 0.

Comment: `!(x < 0)` and `x >= 0` are different if `x` is not-a-number.

Comment: Thanks MartinNyolt and @aschepler this is helfup. And the literal 0.0 is not changing this somehow?

Comment: thank you very much, so the sign doesn't really matter here, i was worried about the -0 since i wanted only not negative (positive and zero) and -0 is not negative, its still just 0 so its ok.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html) might answer your question. Zero has its own noninterchangeable representation. Whether the value is positive or negative is represented by the *sign* bit.

Citing from the article:

> if every bit is zero (the sign bit being irrelevant), then the number is considered zero.

Hence the positive/negative zero must have no impact on the comparison operations - it is still a zero.

Comment: Thx I'll try to read that, but I'm not now in the mood to read any long articles.

Comment: Please include the relevant information of the link you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can test both
if(myDoubleValue >= 0.0)
and
if(!(myDoubleValue < 0.0))

Comment: I know i can test both, but will it give the exact same result for every possible double value? Especially around 0.

Comment: Yes it will give the exact same result for every possible double value even for around zero in c and c++ programming language.